# Regex stop after last slash

Tags: java, regex

I'm very new to regex and I am trying to figure out this:

```
/games/athem
/games/athem/countdown
```

I want to get the whole line until the last /

So `/games/athem` should be valid
but not `/games/athem/countdown`

```
(.*)$
```

This gives me everything, but I want to stop at the `/`. Also, how do I make sure it only works on `/games/` and not, for example, `/companies/athem`?

How would I do this? I tried searching but couldnt find something. Its just really confusing

Comment: Maybe [`^(?:/[^/]+){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/h9v4Ao/1) will do?

Comment: Great that works! I also escaped the / now. ^(?:\/[^\/]+){2}$

Comment: Why escape `/`? Are you using JavaScript? What is the tool/language?

Comment: Oh I dont have to do that? No using Java. How do I make sure it only works on /games/ and not for exampe /companies/athem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^/games/[^/]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9v4Ao/3).

In Java, omit the anchors when using the pattern with the `matches()` method:

```
s.matches("/games/[^/]+")
```

Note you do not need to escape a `/` in a string pattern since `/` is not a special regex metacharacter and Java regex does not use regex delimiters.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches()`)
- `/games/` - a literal `/games/` substring
- `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `matches()`).

Comment: Why not just `^(.*/)+`?

Comment: @TheChetan OP seems to need just 2 subparts, starting with `games`